# Click no botão não funciona

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Tenho um botão feito no `ext`, que ele deve abrir uma janela quando o Selenium clicasse, porem isso não acontece, estou fazendo da seguinte forma.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    import unittest

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("mywebsite")

    def ClickFunction(self):
            driver = self.driver
            driver.find_element_by_class_name(' x-form-file-input').click


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

o cmd não retorna erros.

```
Ran 1 test in 5.580s

OK
```

onde posso estar errando? ja tentei por name, id.. nenhum funciona

Comment: Boa tarde, por favor poste um código que possa ser, leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - espero que entenda como uma critica construtiva,

Comment: Já possuía um pedaço do código, mas anyway adicionei o que é necessário.

Comment: Isto `driver.find_element_by_class_name(' x-form-file-input')` não deveria ser isto `driver.find_element_by_class_name('x-form-file-input')` (sem espaço)?

Comment: o nome do botão é com o espaçamento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o evento:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name(' x-form-file-input').click
```

Deva ser chamado assim `.click()` e o metodo `find_element_by_class_name` busca tags com o atributo `class` e não `name` ou `id`.

### Usando o método `class_name`

Você deve ter em mente que tanto no Javascript quanto HTML quanto qualquer coisa que entenda o DOM o atributo `class=""` funciona TOTALMENTE diferente dos outros atributos, busca por `class_name` é diferente de atributos normais, o **argumento** no método `find_element_by_class_name` **não pode conter espaços**, deve ser assim:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('x-form-file-input')
```

Ele pega elementos que contenha a string entre espaços, ele vai "pegar" elementos como:

```
<input class="x-form-file-input">
<input class="abc x-form-file-input">
<input class="x-form-file-input def">
<input class="abc x-form-file-input def">
<input class=" x-form-file-input "> (veja aqui tem espaço no começo e no fim e será pega também)
<input class=" x-form-file-input"> (veja aqui tem espaço no começo e será pega também)
<input class="x-form-file-input "> (veja aqui tem espaço no fim e será pega também)
```

### Pegando elemento pelo atributo `name=""`

Se o que você quer é o atributo `name=""` assim:

```
<input name="x-form-file-input"></input>
```

Você deve fazer assim:

```
  driver.find_element_by_name('x-form-file-input').click()
```

### Pegando elemento pelo `id=""`

Se o que você quer é o atributo `id=""` assim:

```
  <button id="x-form-file-input"></button>
```

Você deve fazer assim:

```
  driver.find_element_by_id('x-form-file-input').click()
```

### Pegando elemento por um seletor CSS

Você também pode usar por seletor CSS que é mais avançado:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.content .class")
```

Ou pegar por uma ID:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#foo')
```

---

### Abrindo a janela de dialogo com `send_keys`

Nos navegadores não é permitido o uso de Click sem o usuário, quando você chama `.click` ele considera uma ação robotica e a bloqueia, então ao invés disto, use o `send_keys` assim:

```
  driver.find_element_by_class_name('x-form-file-input').send_keys("/");
```

Ou assim:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('x-form-file-input').send_keys("C:");
```

Segue a documentação:

- http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html

Comment: <input id="fileuploadfield-1033-button-fileInputEl" data-ref="fileInputEl" class=" x-form-file-input" type="file" size="1" name="arquivo" role="button" componentid="fileuploadfield-1033-button">

Esse é o meu botão, tentei usar o id, e o name e a classe, e nenhum funcionou

Comment: Editei como exemplos de inputs, veja lá e vê se ficou claro o uso do atributo `class=""` @GuilhermeLima e me avisa se algo falhar ;)

Comment: cara realmente você está certo...descobri o que acontece, ele clicka no botão mas não abre a janela não abre..sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: ele abre um upload file do windows

Comment: :(, ai complicou minha situação, no chrome tb?

Comment: @GuilhermeLima faz um teste assim `driver.find_element_by_class_name('x-form-file-input').send_keys("/");` ou assim `driver.find_element_by_class_name('x-form-file-input').send_keys("C:");` e me avisa

Comment: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendKeys'

Comment: @GuilhermeLima Eu editei o comentário é `send_keys`

Comment: Cara, parabéns funcionou. não sei como agradecer :D